# Python and plot() : how to limit the number of x-axis ticks (labels)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two lists, same size, one is y_data and one is x_data
x_data is a time hh:mm:ss during day, in fact each minute
each serie is 1440 long.

problem is :

```
fig = Figure(figsize=(4,3))
a = gif.add_subplot(111)
a.plot(x_data, y_data)
```

give an unreadable x_axis (too many labels), if i reduce x_data to `[range(24)]` for instance, plot gives an error.

Question :

I'd like to have only 24 items on x_axis scale (each hour, so 1 item each 60 x_data points)
is there a simple way to achieve this ? `set_autoscale_on(False)` and then manually setting limits seems a very complex way to achieve this (and I would loose the benefits from autoscaling on y axis).
Another solution seems to involve `a.xaxis.set_ticks()` but i have to crate a new serie.

o I'd like to use x_data but just limit the number of ticks shown on x_axis, is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 7):

The pyplot interface of matplotlib provides a function [locator_params](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.locator_params), where you can set this option:

```
fig = Figure(figsize=(4,3))
a = fig.add_subplot(111)
a.plot(x_data, y_data)
a.locator_params(nbins=4)
```

Comment: gives 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'locator_params'

Comment: What matplotlib version do you have? It definitely works on my computer, where version 1.1.0 is installed.

Comment: you're right, i was 0.99, upgraded to 1.0.1-3 and it works - thx for your help

Comment: This is a good method, but this changes the number of ticks on both the x and the y axis. If you want to set the number of ticks on just the x-axis, change the last line to "a.locator_params(nbins=4,axis='x')"